# how to filter an array with contains property in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, contains

the (commented lines) works but it only filters the products that initiates with the word im writing

what im trying to do if filtering if the name contains whatever im writing in the search bar

the while method is how im trying to solve it but is not working at all

I've tried using the contains method of the function but it shows me tons of results it duplicates the results

```
// productosBuscados=productos.filter{$0.Descripcion.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count)==searchText.lowercased()}//

        var contador=0
        while contador<productos.count-1{
            if(productos[contador].Descripcion.contains(buscador.text!)){
                productosBuscados.append(productos[contador])
                print(productos[contador].Descripcion+" este producto concuerda")
            }
            contador+=1
        }
        buscando = true
        tabla.reloadData()
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65640752/5623035). If i'm not, please explain more about the issue and add some product examples for demo.

Comment: Hey, did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using searchBar for solving this kind of problems. Here is an example of how you use the searchBar;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {

    //MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var serachBar: UISearchBar!
    
    //MARK: - Variables
    var rawData:[String] = ["Taha","Yasin","Samet","Sumeyye","Seda","Esra","Muhammet","Zeynep","Ishak","Fatma"]
    var filteredData:[String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        serachBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = rawData
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? rawData : rawData.filter {
            $0.contains(searchText)
        }
        //It prints the data from the filtered array contains the text that you searched from the search bar and the print method will be called after every caracter that you add the search bar.
        print(filteredData)
    }
}
```

Comment: nice approach kanka :)

Comment: actually that's what im trying  but it seems not working

Answer (score 1):

Just write it as you say it:

```
let result = products.filter { $0.Descripcion.contains("whatever im writing in the search bar") }
```

Comment: This is actually already part of the question

Comment: It is similar to that, not the same @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes not exactly the same but how does this fix the issue OP is having when using `contains`?

Comment: The OP is using "count" and "prefix" in the question and that is not expected. This code is the correct usage of what the title is asking for. Also it will not return duplicate results. The op can provide some samples if he faces edge case errors again :)

Comment: Please read the question again. It’s the code in the while loop we are discussing but I agree it’s a bit weird with duplicates

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Can you explain please? 

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for all that replied the solution was this one

```
productosBuscados = buscador.text!.isEmpty ? productos : productos.filter {
            $0.Descripcion.lowercased().contains(buscador.text!.lowercased())
        }
```